# How to implement nested checkboxs

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I want to show a checkbox list inside another checkbox list.

I have tables and they store `permissions`, `permission groups`, `role permissions` and `roles`.

Now I want to show permissions in a checkbox list like this :

```
-Permission Group |_|
   Permission |_|
   Permission |_|
   Permission |_|
-Permissions Group2 |_|
   Permission1 |_|
   Permission2 |_|
+PermissionGroup3 |_|
```

By clicking on `+`, it shows some items in that group.

I have 2 lists, children and parents. I want to show parents and inside of each parent show the children of that parent.

Comment: you can use `Treeview` control

Comment: Also just as important. You should make a proper tree structure back end to handle your logic.